# Why do show coefficients strange pattern in regression (mixed-model) with *duration in shift* and *hour of day* on reaction time?

Tags: regression, time-series, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, panel-data

I want to analyze, how the duration a worker is in a shift affects reaction time. I want to control for hour of day, because work condition change across a day. The duration in shift is not the same as hour of day, because workers start their shift at different times of day (within and between variation).

My results suggest that the longer a worker is in a shift the longer the reaction time and, at the same time, the later the hour the shorter the reaction time, which seems odd. The work conditions should not be better at the end of the day. I think I made some mistake, does somebody know what is going on? Might have something to do with the correlation between the variables and that one is numeric and the other one categorical?

I use mixed-models with the lme4-package and the formula is as follows:

ReactionTimeSLog ~ DurationInShiftMinZ + Hour + (1|UserId) + (1|Stimulus).

Duration in shift is numeric and z-transformed. Hour is categorial with hour 8 as the reference category.

The results:
[image]

And vif:

[image]

Comment: "...the later the hour the shorter the reaction time..." Maybe it's the circadian rhythm, instead of just later hour in the day?

Comment: Circadian rhytmn should be included in time in shift. I only selected morning shifts (starting before 8 o'clock), so time in shift should be a mixture of circadian rhytmn and fatique.